# How to restrict to add an item to List<T>?

Tags: c#, list, properties, code-access-security

I have Class called `Person` containing to properties, Father and List of Children.

I want every one to use only `AddChild` Method to add children, not the `List.Add` method ,
so how do I restrict use of it?

```
public class Person
{
  private List<Person> _children = new List<Person>();
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Person Father { get; set; }
  public List<Person> Children 
  { 
    get
    {
       return _children;
    } 
  }
  public void AddChild(string name)
  {
      _children.Add( new Person { Name = name, Father = this });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please see [How to make List's Add method protected, while exposing List with get property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260665/how-to-make-lists-add-method-protected-while-exposing-list-with-get-property?rq=1) for some more detailed answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your Children property to this:

```
public IList<Person> Children 
{ 
  get
  {
     return _children.AsReadOnly();
  } 
}
```

Comment: That said, the `Children` of any instance of a `Person` class will be accessed via this getter, so yes, they will be *in this case*. But generally speaking, using `.AsReadOnly()` only makes the `List<T>` itself readonly, not the items in the list.

Answer (score 12):

Expose Children as ReadOnlyCollection:

```
public IList<Person> Children  
{  
    get 
    { 
       return new ReadOnlyCollection<Person>(_children);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Expose `Children` as `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 7):

If you are exposing the underlying `List<T>`, then in short: you can't.

You could write your own collection-wrapper class, or perhaps inherit from `Collection<T>` (which still exposes `Add`, but you can `override` a few things to sense-check data before it is added).

Comment: Derive Children class from Collection<T>, and override AddItem() Function to attach father to the item is better option

Answer (score 3):

Expose the Children property as `ReadOnlyCollection<Person>`

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<Person> Children
{
     get {return _children.AsReadOnly();}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using .NET 4.5 or greater, you can return `_children` as [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public IReadOnlyList<Person> Children
{
    get
    {
        return _children;
    }
}
```

How is this different from returning an `IList<Person>` via `_children.AsReadOnly()`? `IReadOnlyList<Person>` doesn't even have the mutation methods. Consider the following code:

```
somePerson.Children[0] = null;
```

When using `IReadOnlyList<Person>` this code will fail to compile. When using `.AsReadOnly()` this code will result in a runtime exception.

How is this different from returning an `ReadOnlyCollection<Person>` via `_children.AsReadOnly()`? There's no `ReadOnlyCollection<Person>` wrapper object created. Aside from that, I'm not seeing a huge difference.

Answer (score 2):

An IEnumerable works just fine:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Children
{
    get
    {
        return _children.AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```

or the more long winded:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Children
{
    get
    {
        foreach (Person child in _children)
        {
            yield return child;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Matthew, thanks for pointing that out. Actually, this reminded me that AsEnumerable() is just a cast of the reference to the List, client code could simply cast back to List<Person> and mutate the "private" List at will. I've updated the example code appropriately.