# How to make List's Add method protected, while exposing List with get property?

Tags: c#, list, properties

I have a class named WhatClass that has List field in it. I need to be able to read-only this field, so I used a get property to expose it to other objects.

```
public class WhatClass
{
    List<SomeOtherClass> _SomeOtherClassItems;

    public List<SomeOtherClass> SomeOtherClassItems { get { return _SomeOtherClassItems; } }
}
```

However it turns out that any object can call

```
WhatClass.SomeOtherClassItems.Add(item);
```

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As others have said, you are looking for the `.AsReadOnly()` extension method.

However, you should store a reference to the collection instead of creating it during each property access:

```
private readonly List<SomeOtherClass> _items;

public WhatClass()
{
    _items = new List<SomeOtherClass>();

    this.Items = _items.AsReadOnly();
}

public ReadOnlyCollection<SomeOtherClass> Items { get; private set; }
```

This is to ensure that `x.Items == x.Items` holds true, which could otherwise be very unexpected for API consumers.

Exposing `ReadOnlyCollection<>` communicates your intent of a read-only collection to consumers. Changes to `_items` will be reflected in `Items`.

Comment: You might want to elaborate for the masses what happens when you add to _items and how you deal with that...

Comment: @Dave - The docs state that changes will be reflected in the wrapper.

Comment: Bryan, thank you very much for this answer, although I do not need a readonly keyword here.

Comment: @Witchunter: you aren't assigning `_items` after the constructor; the `readonly` keyword communicates that intent: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx. If you plan on assigning another value to `_items` after `WhatClass` is constructed, you will also need to reassign the `Items` property.

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for the [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx), which is a read-only wrapper around an `IList<T>`.

Since the `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` will reflect changes in the underlying list, you don't need to create a new instance every time.

For example:

```
public class WhatClass {
    public WhatClass() {
        _SomeOtherClassItems = new List<SomeOtherClass>();
        SomeOtherClassItems = _SomeOtherClassItems.AsReadOnly();
    }

    List<SomeOtherClass> _SomeOtherClassItems;

    public ReadOnlyCollection<SomeOtherClass> SomeOtherClassItems { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mentioned ReadOnlyCollection<T> class, but didn't include it in the code, but I've figured it out. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`List<T>.AsReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx):

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<SomeOtherClass> SomeOtherClassItems
{
    get
    {
        return _SomeOtherClassItems.AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```

This will return a [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx), which will throw an exception if a client calls Add through the interface.  In addition, the ReadOnlyCollection type does not expose a public Add method.

Comment: Don't make a new instance each time.

Comment: @SLaks: I see your point, but that's a micro-optimization and I believe it's easier to read this way.  ReadOnlyCollection is small and the GC is good at dealing with small short-lived objects, and you're just as likely to wind up using more memory by adding a field and a ReadOnlyCollection object that you don't need for every one of your classes.

Comment: Allocating objects in a property getter is a bad idea.  People generally assume that a accessing a property getter is nothing more than a memory read, and will therefore access the property many times in large nested loops.

Comment: @SLaks: Never mind, I see the argument about reference equality in Bryan's answer.  I hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 3):

How about using `AsReadOnly()`? - [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

`List<T>` implements `IReadOnlyList<T>` [since .NET Framework 4.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.5), so an internal list can be exposed as `IReadOnlyList<T>` instead for that purpose.

```
public class WhatClass
{
    List<SomeOtherClass> _SomeOtherClassItems;

    public IReadOnlyList<SomeOtherClass> SomeOtherClassItems => _SomeOtherClassItems;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use ToList() to return a copy of the list instead.  Other classes can do what they like to the copy it won't alter your original list.

You should make it clear in the name that they are getting a copy.

```
using System.Linq;

public class WhatClass
{
    List<SomeOtherClass> _SomeOtherClassItems;

    public List<SomeOtherClass> SomeOtherClassItems { get { return _SomeOtherClassItems.ToList(); } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although others have pointed out the use of `ReadOnlyCollection`, it's worth noting that there also exists a cool `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`. It can be really useful in bindings and view models. As [pointed here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlyobservablecollection-1#remarks):

> This class is a read-only wrapper around an ObservableCollection. If changes are made to the underlying collection, the ReadOnlyObservableCollection reflects those changes. To be notified of the changes to this class, subscribe to the CollectionChanged or PropertyChanged event.

You can simply expose this `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` and make changes to the underlying collection and rest assured that your view is getting updated.