# Limit use of List.Add() outside of class that holds it

Tags: c#, xaml, collections, encapsulation

I have a public property of type `List<>` in class `MyClass`.  It is public because code outside of `MyClass` (including the XAML bindings) need to be able to access and change the data.  However, the one thing that elements outside of `MyClass` should NOT be able to do is call the `Add()` method. The only way to add a new method to the list should be through the `MyClass.MyListAdder()` method.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260665/how-to-make-lists-add-method-protected-while-exposing-list-with-get-property

Comment: Expose it as `IEnumerable` or as `IReadOnlyList`

Comment: @thesystem - yes.  That answers my questions.  Somehow I didn't get the magical search terms to pop that up.  `IReadOnlyList<>` or `ReadOnlyCollection<>` both seem to do what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try switching to `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`. It has slightly different API than `List<T>` but might be good enough for your needs.

Comment: Partial answer. Thanks to other commenter I was able to find how to implement `ReadOnlyCollection<>` as a wrapper to `List<>` as explained in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260665/how-to-make-lists-add-method-protected-while-exposing-list-with-get-property

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
List<object> someList = new List<object>();

public ReadOnlyCollection<object> SomeList
{
    get
    {
        return someList.AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```