# Encapsulation of arrays, should I deep copy?

Tags: c#, arrays, oop, encapsulation

A class has a private array/list. It is encapsuled by only allowing editing through methods like "AddElement".

Now another class needs information about all elements of that array/list.

Passing the reference of the array/list would break the encapsulation. Returning a new array/list but with the same objects would still allow manipulating the objects. Creating a deep copy feels a bit like overkill. Is there a better way?

As an example:
In a game, I have multiple units. To put markers on a minimap, the unit's position and unit type is needed by the renderer. The renderer should not be able to change all kinds of properties of the units.

I'm doing this in C#.

Comment: Pass a `ReadOnlySpan`? Or some custom written equivalent

Comment: You have AddElement, now you need GetElements.

Comment: Can you provide more details on why another class needs the elements. If its just for access purpose you can have functions like GetCount() and GetElementAtIndex() to achieve it. If it performs some querying on data, you can functions specific to that. Else I suppose creating the deep copy is the only feasible solution.

Comment: @Jasmeet I added more information on how and why I want to encapsule.

Comment: Perhaps [List<T>.AsReadOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.asreadonly?view=net-6.0) fits to your needs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make List's Add method protected, while exposing List with get property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260665/how-to-make-lists-add-method-protected-while-exposing-list-with-get-property)

Comment: "To put markers on a minimap, the unit's position and unit type" - so you just need to expose that specific metadata. You could create a "MarkerMetadata" type with two readonly properties and spit out 1 of those for each object in the list when needed - that way, you can still expose the required info without exposing the actual objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new method which will expose only the needed info. Something like:

```
public (Point Position, string UnitType) GetUnitInfo()
{
    return _units.Select(u => (u.Position, u.UnitType));
}
```